# How to set "{Binding}" in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, code-behind

There is a [nice control](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) from Thomas Levesque:

```
<local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
```

I'd like to *hide* `Data` initialization into constructor, to simply use it like this:

```
<local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" />
```

Here is my not working attempt (complete code in case link die):

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public BindigProxy()
    {
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DataProperty, new Binding { Source = this });
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why `Source = this`? `Data="{Binding}"` is equivalent to `BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DataProperty, new Binding());`

Comment: @Clemens, that's it, thanks. Is there a duplicate? If not, post it as an answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not set the `Source` property of the Binding. You also did not do that in XAML.

The equivalent of the XAML expression `Data="{Binding}"` is

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, DataProperty, new Binding());
```